# How to let text editors (or Gtk text view component) respect my font settings for leading whitespace for correct indentation?

Tags: gtk, editors, mate-desktop, fontconfig

In the MATE desktop environment (Debian Linux 12), the width of the rendered leading spaces seems to be different according to different languages, in rich text like components. Including the text views in *pluma*/*gedit*, *abiword*, etc.

I have pre-selected a font (`PT Mono Regular` in this case) and a font size (14pt), but the leading space widths can be different for different language lines:

[image: Part 1: Wrong indentation space width]

The font `PT Mono Regular` actually defined the space char. This can be examined with command *fc-query*:

```
$ fc-query --format='%{charset}\n' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/paratype/PTM55F.ttf 
20-7e a0-109 10c-113 116-11f 122-127 12a-12b ...
```

Codepoint range *20-7e* shows the font contains the space char *\u0020*.

I guess the view component determines the font to use to render the whitespace by checking the first non-space char, but not the space char defined in the selected font. If so, can I get rid of the "AI whitespace font" feature? **Maybe some libgtk config lines?**

When the problem can be fixed by prefix lines with a symbol char:

[image: Part 2: Correct space widths while they are not leading space]

So, the view component seems to "guess" the font to use to render the space: only checking the chars before but not after the space. The only exception rule is when the whitespace is at the line leading (usually for indentation), since there's no letter before the space, the editor tries to find out the language by searching letters after the space, while usually it searches the letter before the space.

However, if I use the tab char *\u0009* instead of space char *\u0020* for indentation, the tab char could work. Some text editors like *atom* just treat the leading *\u0020* spaces by grouping them as tabs. For example, you can delete 4 *\u0020* spaces by one *backspace* keystroke in *atom* or *vscode*.

The following screenshot shows what it looks like the text editor choose different fonts to render the space:

[image: Part 3: notice the different space char widths.]

According the the font file, only the first line (english) use the space defined in the *PTM55F.ttf* file. Well, It's reasonable to render spaces in different widths for different languages, as the spaces comes to the middle of the text, the space width reflects the language writing style.

However, the leading spaces are usually for indentation, by default they should be sized to the font user selected, to get the most expected render result.

The problem also exists for other fonts. And it seems particularly obvious for *Monospace* family fonts.

**Maybe fontconfig do the tricks?**

[Sample text file](http://0x0.st/H2ZX.txt)

Comment: Wow! That is surprising! I wonder what the unicode encoding of these different language looks like, and when unicode plane switching happens. Could you share that "broken" example file with us? Assuming you call it "text.txt", an easy way to do so is, from the same directory it is in, open a console and run `curl -F 'file=@-' 0x0.st < text.txt` from there, and sharing the link you get from that!

Comment: Interesting web cmd. http://0x0.st/H2ZX.txt